# Besides Logo and Emacs Lisp, what are other pure dynamically scoped languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, lisp, programming-languages, language-theory, logo-lang

What are some examples of a dynamically scoped language? And what are the reasons for choosing that design? Is it because it is easy to implement?

Comment: Once upon a time, all Lisp versions I knew of had dynamic scoping.  elisp is one of the last survivors of that time.

Answer (score 11):

Mathematica is another language that is dynamically scoped, via the `Block` construct. This is actually quite useful when working with formulas. It allows you to write things like

```
 In[1]:= expr = a*t^2 + b*t+ c;

 In[2]:= Block[{a = 1, b = -1, c = 2}, Table[expr, {t, 5}]]
 Out[2]= {2, 4, 8, 14, 22}
```

which wouldn't work at all if variables like `a` and `t` were scoped lexically. It works particularly nicely with Mathematica's rule-rewriting system, which will, among other things, leave variables unevaluated (as symbolic expressions) if it doesn't have an existing definition for them.

Mathematica can fake lexical scoping with the `Module` construct, but what this really does is rewrite the expression in terms of new, allegedly unique symbol (you can cause clashes if you predict what the next unique symbol will be, which is easy in most cases). This means

```
Module[{x = 4}, 
  Table[x * t, {t, 5}]]
```

will be turned into something like this:

```
Block[{x$134 = 4},
  Table[x$134 * t, {t, 5}]
```

Emacs Lisp, in one of its libraries, has a construct (really a Lisp macro) called `lexical-let` that pulls exactly the same trick to fake lexical scoping.

There are performance advantages to real lexical scoping when you're compiling your language which you don't get with the fake lexicals of ELisp or Mathematica, since you need some mapping between the dynamic variable and its current value, which means doing lookups (through a hash table or property list or something) and additional layers of indirection.

**EDIT**: If you have only lexical variables, you can fake dynamic scoping by storing the original value of a global, lexical variable on entering the scope and guaranteeing that the old value is restored upon exiting the scope. In order to ensure that, you'll need something like Lisp's `UNWIND-PROTECT` or a `finally` block. I've seen this done using C++ destructors as well, mostly as an exercise.

Answer (score 9):

Dynamically scoped languages are much easier to implement. To access variables which is not in the current activaiton record / stack frame, one just follows the control links. Static/lexical access links are then not needed, making stack frames smaller.

Dynamic variables can be "unpredictable" at runtime, because one needs to know in which order the actual stackframes are to know which variable will be used. This information is not available by just looking at the static structure of the code. One could quite easily get caught out if the actual call graph of the program is not easy to predict at implementation time. Thats why most languages today have static scoping (most Exception systems however, are dynamic as this is the most practical).

However in some cases, dynamically scoped variables are very useful. For example when redirecting output, you could using dynamic variables set standard output for local code and all code called from there on.

```
(let ((*standard-output* *some-other-stream*))
 (stuff))
```

In this common-lisp example (from Seibel), standard output is bound to another stream for the duration of the let form, (inside its enclosing parens). When execution leaves the let, it goes back to whatever it was beforehand. See http://gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html Peter Seibels free and excellent book, Practical Common Lisp, for a good discussion. In Seibels own words:

> Dynamic bindings make global variables much more manageable, but it's important to notice they still allow action at a distance. Binding a global variable has two at a distance effects--it can change the behavior of downstream code, and it also opens the possibility that downstream code will assign a new value to a binding established higher up on the stack. You should use dynamic variables only when you need to take advantage of one or both of these characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

All the shell languages (bash, ksh, etc) use dynamic scoping.

Comment: The `fish` shell is a notable exception

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's a bunch of websites that discuss the pro's and con's, so I'm not going there.

One interesting language that has some features that faintly resemble dynamic scope is XSLT; although XSLT's templates and variables and the like are lexically scoped, XSLT is of course all about XML - and the current position in the xml tree is "dynamically scoped" in the sense that the context node is global and thus that XPath expressions are evaluated not according to XSLT's lexical scope but according to it's dynamic evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic scope is/was easier to implement with interpreters. Most early Lisp interpreters were using dynamic scope. After several years lexical scope was found to have an advantage, but was first mostly implemented in Lisp compilers. Several implementations appeared that implemented dynamic scope in interpreted code and lexical scope in compiled code. Some provided a special language construct to provide closures. Lisp dialects like Scheme and Common Lisp required then that there is no difference between interpreted and compiled code and thus interpreted based implementations had to implement lexical scope, too.

Early Smalltalk implementations implemented dynamic scope. All kinds of Lisp dialect implementations implemented dynamic scope (Interlisp, UCI Lisp, Lisp Machine Lisp, MacLisp, ...).

Almost all new Lisp dialects from the last 20 years use lexical scope by default or even exclusively. Several publications have described in detail how to implement Lisp with lexical scope - so there is no excuse not to use lexical scope.

Answer (score 0):

m4 has pushdef/popdef which is a typical dynamic scope implementation.